# What does this "a file local variable" mean?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am reading about the `kill-emacs-hook` variable in the emacs manual.
It says:

> `kill-emacs-hook` is a variable defined in `C source code'.
>   Its value is
>   `(org-babel-remove-temporary-directory migemo-pattern-alist-save)`
>
> This variable is potentially risky when used as a file local variable.
>
> Documentation:
>   Hook to be run when ``kill-emacs`' is called.
>   ...abbr...

I do not understand this sentence: "a file local variable". What does this "a file local variable" mean?

Answer (score 4):

Emacs has a facility for specifying buffer variables in a file's contents. http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables

This is frequently used to specify the file's mode `-*- python -*-` or e.g. the preferred indentation style or tab width; but it potentially can give the file's author complete control over your Emacs, if you allow it. However, for variables deemed to be unsafe, the default behavior is to ask the user for confirmation before permitting the settings to take effect. See the manual for further discussion.

Answer (score 2):

By defaul, when you set a variable with `setq` the value is global. It means that all the buffers will see the new value.

However, certain variables, called buffer local variables, work differently. When a buffer local variable is set, its value changes only for the buffer where the `setq` happened. The other buffers do not see the change.

These buffer local variables can take their value from the content of the file currently visited by the buffer. If the file contains a properly formatted string (see @tripleee's answer) then a buffer local variable will be initialized with the value when the file is open.

As a side note, directory local variables also exist which set a buffer local variable for every buffer visiting a file in the directory.